# Recorded calls of WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, call-recording

I need one call recording through WhatsApp.

I have searched for too long, but I didn't find the solution anywhere.

From where I could get my own WhatsApp call recordings?

Comment: Call recording has different laws in different countries across the globe, so it can't be a standard feature. WhatsApp doesn't record calls, you have to set up manually. But most of the third party solutions don't work either, particularly without rooting phone.

Answer (score 2):

WhatsApp does not record the calls automatically. So, if you didn't rely on a 3rd party app (I can't make a recommendation) and you did not record the call when it happened, you cannot find any recordings of the same. This makes it impossible to get that call conversation back.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp introduced recording voice calls in v2.12.45 beta version, which is capable of recording voice calls. It is a leaked internal-only version, which is presently being used by the engineers for testing and debugging VoIP calls.

Thus, depending on the WhatsApp version, you may find it on `/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Calls`.

[image: /WhatsApp Calls]